# Global API call Vue.js

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

I'm having trouble creating a global variable that contains API.
I need to use this variable throughout my app, so it will be easier to change API link when the time comes.
How can I do that?
So far I've done the following:

Created a file called config.js

```
const baseURL = 'http://myapi'

export default {
    baseURL
}
```

I'm using Vuex to make api calls so the part where I try to receive data looks like this in my store:

```
import baseURL from '../../../config.js'

    async fetchStaff({ commit }, id, baseURL) {
    if (id === undefined) {
        const response = await axios.get(baseURL + `/employee/staff`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}` } });
        commit('setStaff', response.data);
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(response.data)
    } else {
        const response = await axios.get(baseURL + `/employee/${id}`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}` } });
        commit('setStaff', response.data);
    }
},
```

baseURL is undefind in store.
Can someone point out the mistake here, please?

Comment: You're exporting a default object and importing that object, naming it in the process. You either want to `import { baseURL } from ...` or reference it as `baseURL.baseURL`, likely the former.

Answer (score 0):

config.js

```
// Bases
export const baseURL = 'http://myapi'

// Endpoints
export const api_1 = '/api1'
export const api_2 = param1 => `/api2/ + ${param1}`
```

store.js

```
// import apis you want to use this file.
import { baseURL, api_1 } from '../../../config.js'
```

Comment: The objective is to explain why it doesn't work and then provide answers.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're exporting an object in your config.js.
so if you import it like below:

`import baseURL from '../../../config.js'`

Then you will get the whole object of configs. Instead, you could import the baseURL variable by doing this:

`import { baseURL } from '../../../config.js'`

Second, in this line:

> async fetchStaff({ commit }, id, **baseURL**)

baseURL is recognized as a parameter. that's why it always has no value or `undefined`, I would recommend removing it from the function parameter. 
So it will probably look like  below:

```
import { baseURL } from '../../../config.js'


async fetchStaff({ commit }, id) {
    if (id === undefined) {
        const response = await axios.get(baseURL + `/employee/staff`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}` } });
        commit('setStaff', response.data);
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(response.data)
    } else {
        const response = await axios.get(baseURL + `/employee/${id}`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}` } });
        commit('setStaff', response.data);
    }
},
```

thanks